# Showing div element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

First of all I apologize if this question had been asked before and I apologize for my bad english.
I get into trouble when making this script by using CodeIgniter.

This is my Controller

```
function add()
{
    $data = array(
        'company' => $this->m_company->get_company_profile(),
        'title' => 'Transaksi',
        'page_header' => 'Tambah Transaksi',
        'userName' => 'administrator',
        'userLevel' => 'admin',
        'itemData'=>$this->m_stock->getItemSell(),
        'buyerData' => $this->m_buyer->getAllData('buyers')
        );
    // 
    $this->template->load('_admin-template', 'admin/transaction-add', $data);
}

function getBuyerData()
{
    $id['buyerCode'] = $this->input->post('buyerCode');
    $data = array(
        'detailBuyer' => $this->m_buyer->getSelectedData('buyers', $id)->result()
        );
    $this->load->view('admin/transaction/detail-buyer', $data);
}
```

This is my m_buyer (model)

```
function getAllData($table)
{
    return $this->db->get($table)->result();
}

public function getSelectedData($table, $data)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($table, $data);
}
```

and this is my view (transaction-add) but just few not all i show here

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label for="buyerCode" class="control-label">Pembeli :</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="buyerCode" id="buyerCode" style="width:250px" data-placeholder="Pilih Pembeli">
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
        if(isset($buyerData)){
        foreach($buyerData as $row){?>
        <option value="<?php echo ($row->buyerCode);?>"><?php echo ($row->buyerCode);?> <?php echo ($row->full_name);?></option>
        <?php
             }
        }?>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="showBuyer"><!-- buyer data show here --!></div>
```

And this is my JQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buyerCode").change(function(){
        var buyerCode = $("#buyerCode").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "<?php echo base_url('admin/transaction/getBuyerData');?>",
            data: "buyerCode="+buyerCode,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                $('#showBuyer').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

my another view detail-buyer

```
    <?php
    if(isset($detailBuyer)){
    foreach($detailBuyer as $row){
        ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <label for="address" class="control-label">Address :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" id="address" value="<?php echo ($row->address);?>" readonly="readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <label for="region" class="control-label">Region :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="region" class="form-control" id="region" value="<?php echo ($row->region);?>" readonly="readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <label for="province" class="control-label">Provence :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="province" class="form-control" id="province" value="<?php echo ($row->province);?>" readonly="readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
                    <label for="postalCode" class="control-label">Postal Code :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="postalCode" class="form-control" id="postalCode" value="<?php echo ($row->postalCode);?>" readonly="readonly>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <?php
         }
       }
     ?>
```

So, when i choose buyer from selection list in the transaction-add, the detail-buyer should appear inside . But unfortunately, it did not happen.
Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Your POST is probably failing, that's why you're not seeing anything in the `showBuyer` `<div>`.What I would suggest is modify your ajax call to have an error call back and check if the error block gets called when you make the AJAX call.

Use Ctrl+Shift+J in Google Chrome to open up the javascript console and step through your javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url : "<?php echo base_url('admin/transaction/getBuyerData');?>",
    data: "buyerCode="+buyerCode,
    cache:false,
    success: function(data){
        $('#showBuyer').html(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
        debugger;
        alert('An error occurred...');
    }
});
```

Also your URL parameter doesn't look right.Usually the examples I see of calling php file have URLs like - `url:"admin/transaction/getBuyerData.php"`

Comment: Op using codeigniter which has controller routing. Last line is incorrect

Comment: Thanks Denis Wessels for your answer.

About URLs parameter is to run getBuyerData function in my Controller.
and my bad, i forget to recheck what i write... i always write <?php echo base_url();?>controller/function but in that script i write <?php echo base_url('admin/controller/function');?>

Comment: So did my answer help you or not?I can't really tell from your comment

Answer (score 0):

Click F12 (firefox or chrome) and find console tab... when you click -- with the console open -- you should either receive an error message of why it is failed or additional information to help you get on track.

Also to double test your code... you can run your `$('#showBuyer').html(data);` code in the console to see if it works, just remember to change the data variable to a string of your chosing.